# iam role authenticated via Azure AD Workbench Redshift

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, amazon-redshift, amazon-iam, sql-workbench-j

I have been trying to authenticate to redshift via IAM from workbench/J, and having followed various links :
https://medium.com/tensult/aws-redshift-authentication-with-adfs-4ba423e2dc96
https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/redshift/latest/mgmt/generating-user-credentials.html
I still am unable to connect.

My Workbench looks like :

```
Driver : com.amazon.redshift.jdbc.Driver
url : jdbc:redshift:iam://<cluster-name>:<region>/<db>
username : org email id
password : org email id password

extended properties :
DbUser  employeeid
idp_port    443
AutoCreate  true
plugin_name com.amazon.redshift.plugin.AzureCredentialsProvider
idp_host    domain-id
preferred_role arn-of-IAM-Role
```

The IAM Role has the following policy attached already :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "redshift:DescribeClusters",
                "iam:ListRoles"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "GetClusterCredsStatement",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "redshift:GetClusterCredentials"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:redshift:*:*:dbname:<cluster>/<db>",
                "arn:aws:redshift:*:*:dbuser:<cluster>/${Redshift:DbUser}",
                "arn:aws:redshift:*:*:dbgroup:<cluster>/<dbgroup>"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "CreateClusterUserStatement",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "redshift:CreateClusterUser"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:redshift:*:*:dbname:<cluster>/<db>",
                "arn:aws:redshift:*:*:dbuser:<cluster>/${Redshift:DbUser}"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "RedshiftJoinGroupStatement",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "redshift:JoinGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:redshift:*:*:dbgroup:<cluster>/<dbgroup>"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The following Claim Rules have been added already too :

```
DbUser : user.employeeid
DbGroups : user.assignedroles
Role : the IAM role with policy attached above
RoleSessionName : user.userprincipalname
```

I can furnish more details but I have been simply following what these links say, I have working connections to redshift cluster otherwise.

Edit:

I traced sqlworkbench logs to find : `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/auth/profile/ProfilesConfigFile`

Edit 2:

I launched sql workbench as :

```
java -Dworkbench.log.level=DEBUG -jar sqlworkbench.jar
```

and looking at the `tail -f $Home/.sqlworkbench/workbench.log`

to find out that I had a few jars missing like httpclient, httpcore, aws-sdk-java and a few more.

Now stuck at `idp_tenant required parameter missing`

Edit 2 :
I have now progressed upto :

```
[JDBC Driver]SAML error: invalid_grant: AADSTS50126: Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password. Trace ID: 1c67cec4-bc2e-4140-bdc5-84e72ae50300 Correlation ID: 14be34b2-b9e2-49e5-8415-a388a8839c91 Timestamp: 2020-03-31 06:20:55Z
```

I could evenj decompile the Redshift Jar to look at the source code for AzureCredentialsProvider plugin - this is indeed something wrong at the Azure AD End now. WHile my username/password credentials are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, and it's because the AWS SDK required for the plugin extension is not bundled with the driver jar.

There are 2 solutions:

1. Make the AWS SDK available on the configured java path
2. Download and use a redshift driver bundled with the AWS SDK

For simplicity, I went with the second option. It's a bit unclear from AWS docs but it looks like you have to go to the [driver download documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html#configure-jdbc-options) and scroll down to the section "Use previous JDBC driver versions with the AWS SDK for Java" and select the latest driver from that list.

As further explanation, it looks like AzureCredentialsProvider is provided in the driver jar regardless (which is why you could find it), but the class required is the ProfilesConfigFile class (part of the AWS IAM sdk).

As another sidenote, I was using DataGrip.

Comment: thanks for your reply Jordan, but were you integrating against an "Azure AD" really? Did you get lucky with say : https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/drivers/jdbc/1.2.41.1065/RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.41.1065.jar JAR?

Comment: I've set the `plugin_name=com.amazon.redshift.plugin.AzureCredentialsProvider`. Should this be changed? 
For the driver I downloaded the one with AWS SDK v JDBC42-1.2.43.1067 . I still get the error that the question mentions about invalid login. 
In Pycharm I get the option to select either `com.amazon.redshift.jdbc.Driver` or `com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver` Which did you select to get this working?

Comment: apparantly client_id/secret dont go well with SAML in the JDBC jar for redshift. However, there's this recent post as a success story on azure AD + Redshift. Let's check it out and see if atleast someone has it working at last - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/federate-amazon-redshift-access-with-microsoft-azure-ad-single-sign-on/?